# Change color tab on click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some issue with two tabs in bootstrap. What i want is when i press on a tab, color go to yellow, from black.

You have 2 screenshot with code and design.

Thanks.
[image]

**Second**
 [image]

Comment: Kindly paste the code in the query and not put an image as it becomes difficult to execute the code and help out

Answer (score 0):

When you press on a tab, it gets an `active` class... and it is here that you can style it in the way that you like; Since bootstrap is loaded at the top, we have to make sure that the classes which overwrite the default bootstrap class are set after it is loaded... below snippet should work:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .nav-pills .nav-link {
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: orange;
  }
  
  .nav-pills .nav-link.active {
    color: orange;
    background: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: orange;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the colors in your css file like this:

```
.active {
 color: green;
}
```

and then add a class to your html element with javascript when you click the text:

```
function pillsGreen() {
 var element = document.getElementById("pills-profile");
 element.classList.add("active");
}
```

in your html you can then this code to your div:

```
<div onclick="pillsGreen()" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code starts with "Clienti" on yellow and when you click on "Profile" clienti will be black and "Profile" yellow, and if you click on "Clienty" again it will remove the yellow from "Profile" and have it back in "Clienti".

```js
function changeColor1(){ document.getElementById('profile').classList.remove("yellowColor"); document.getElementById('clienti').classList.add("yellowColor");
};
function changeColor2(){ document.getElementById('clienti').classList.remove("yellowColor"); document.getElementById('profile').classList.add("yellowColor");
};
```

```css
.yellowColor{
    color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1 onclick="changeColor1()" id="clienti" class="yellowColor">Clienti</h1>
<h1 onclick="changeColor2()" id="profile">Profile</h1>
```